# Filmstrip images in android

Tags: android, layout

[image]

I want to have a layout like filmstrip images. Currently i have the layout in which the images gets scrolled in horizontal direction, which is mentioned below.
There are many images and i want a layout like filmstrip. How can i achieve it?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
 <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fruits_back"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />


<ScrollView 
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr1"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:src="@drawable/apple" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr2"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fr1"
        android:src="@drawable/banana" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr3"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fr2"
        android:src="@drawable/blackberry" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr4"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fr3"
        android:src="@drawable/cherries" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr5"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr1"
        android:src="@drawable/custard_apple" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr6"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fr5"
        android:src="@drawable/grapes" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr7"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fr6"
        android:src="@drawable/guava" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr8"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fr7"
        android:src="@drawable/jackfruit" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr9"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr5"
        android:src="@drawable/lemon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr10"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr6"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fr9"
        android:src="@drawable/mango" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr11"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr7"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fr10"
        android:src="@drawable/melon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr12"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr8"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fr11"
        android:src="@drawable/musk_melon" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr13"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr9"
        android:src="@drawable/orange" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr14"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr10"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fr13"
        android:src="@drawable/papaya" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr15"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr11"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fr14"
        android:src="@drawable/peach" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr16"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr12"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fr15"
        android:src="@drawable/pear" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr17"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr13"
        android:src="@drawable/pineapple" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr18"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr14"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fr17"
        android:src="@drawable/plum" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr19"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr15"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fr18"
        android:src="@drawable/pomegranate" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr20"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr16"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/fr19"
        android:src="@drawable/strawberry" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/fr21"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
        android:layout_below="@id/fr17"
        android:src="@drawable/watermelon" />


    </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

Please help

Comment: What is the difference between this layout and _filmstrip_?

Comment: This is just a simple layout but i want to have a layout where the images can be scrolled in horizontal direction from the bottom and the image that is selected should get displayed above it. Check the picture uploaded

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little bit late but since I faced this problem toda and found the answer why not to share?! , as the picture show you have images and you want them to scroll  "and that was my problem" you can replace the scroll view with a list view , but wait!! list view doesn't support horizontal scrolling, so I found this: a horizontal list view:
https://github.com/sephiroth74/HorizontalVariableListView
I hope this'll be helpful for as was for me

*Thanks to my team leader who came up with the idea